# Why is this code showing an error while declaring student[10] in the main function in Java?

Tags: java, class

I am making a Java program. I am trying to use a class "n" times, but it's showing me an error. How can I resolve this?

My code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class student {
    int roll;
    String name;
    void get_data() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        roll = s.nextInt();
        name = s.next();
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println("Rollnumber: " + roll + "\n" + "Name: " + name);
    }
}
```

What should I do with the following part of the code?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rough {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        student stud = new student[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            stud[i] = new student();
            stud[i].get_data();
            stud[i].display();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or insight is welcome.

Comment: student[] stud = new student[10];

Comment: The `student` class isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: As a suggestion,always follow the best practices while coding like here the class name should start with an uppercase letter and this new Student will be an array ```student[] stud = new student[10];```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Why this code showing an error while declaring student[10] in the main function? ..."*

An array is denoted by the `[]` syntax.

Here is the *Java* tutorial on *arrays*.
*[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)*.

So, the declaration should be as follows.

```java
student[] stud = new student[10];
```

Answer (score 2):

`new student[10]` returns an **array of `student`**, not a single `student`. You're missing the square brackets (`[]`) in the variable's declaration:

```java
student[] stud = new student[10];
// Here^
```